# Tirar o menu do login? (AngularJS e UI router)

Tags: angularjs, aplicação-web, ui-router

Boa tarde,

estou participando de um projeto e estou utilizando AngularJS e UI-router, grande parte já está feito, porém eu não sei como posso tirar o menu do login, gostaria que aparecesse somente após a autenticação. Se alguém puder dar uma força ai, agradeço desde já. Segue abaixo print e as rotas.

[image: Menu aparecendo no login]

Rotas:

```
const boletoCorretoraState = {
  name: 'boletoCorretora',
  url: '/boletoCorretoraPublico',
  component: 'boletoCorretora',
};

const boletoEstoqueState = {
  name: 'boletoEstoque',
  url: '/boletoEstoquePublico',
  component: 'boletoEstoque',
};

const consolidadoState = {
  name: 'consolidado',
  url: '/consolidado',
  component: 'consolidado',
};

const consultaState = {
  name: 'consulta',
  url: '/consulta',
  component: 'consulta',
};

const loginState = {
  name: 'login',
  url: '/login',
  component: 'login',
};

$stateProvider.state(boletoCorretoraState);
$stateProvider.state(boletoCorretora2State);
$stateProvider.state(boletoEstoqueState);
$stateProvider.state(boletoEstoque2State);
$stateProvider.state(consolidadoState);
$stateProvider.state(consultaState);
$stateProvider.state(loginState);

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guilherme, no seu caso acredito que daria para aninhar os states que precisam de um usuário logado ([Exemplo de states aninhados](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/hellogalaxy#nesting-states)) e na sua diretiva de menu usar o [$state.is](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/state.stateservice.html#is) para verificar se o estado atual não é mais o login.

Ainda da para consultar seu service/cache para verificar se há um usuário autenticado e evitar a sugestão acima.

Comment: Consegui, muito obrigado!